# How to hide point and dash in numeric keyboardType react native

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm new to react-native. I'm using numeric keyboard type:

```
<TextInput style={styles.TextInputSecond} editable = {true} maxLength={3} keyboardType="numeric" ></TextInput>
```

It is showing `.` and `-` also on the keyboard.

How can I hide or disable (as `,` disabled) them from the keyboard?

[image: keyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and check if it resolve your issue

```
keyboardType={Device.isAndroid ? "numeric" : "number-pad"}
```

or you can also Add

```
const onlyNumber = number.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

this.setState({
  onlyNumber
});
```

TextInput's prop value

```
value={this.state.onlyNumber}
```

Comment: The first one didn't help.

Comment: Can you try both

Comment: We can just make the same as google pay, google pay does not allow for typing hyphens, comma but above solution, I am using a fraction of a second of flicking shows.